# Dynamic azure function trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I’m currently using azure functions with dynamic output binding using binder object. Is there a way to dynamically load triggers too?
Maybe by using host builder?

Comment: Without more information than this we cannot help you, unfortunately. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

No. although trigger is 'direction in', but this doesn't mean there is a way to use dynamic trigger, you need to specify it explicitly in the function declaration section.